# Do merchants ever sell legendary items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've seen mostly Magic (blue) quality items on merchants. Occasionally, I see a Rare (yellow) item. The rare items tend to appear about as often as they drop out in the world, at least from my experience.

That's got me wondering: **Is it possible for a merchant to have a legendary item in his shop?**

Comment: I don't think so... neither greens. but I didn't reach inferno yet to check it. and no source on the web that I have found.

Comment: Legendary items are basically the equivalent to Uniques in Diablo 2, which you could not buy from merchants, except from Gheed via gambling (and even then, the changes of getting a unique was extremely low).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the answer appears to be no - if such a thing is possible, it's so extraordinarily rare that thus far nobody has encountered it and lived to tell the tale. However, it is possible to *craft* legendaries using plans found in Inferno - an expensive proposition, but as close to a vendored legendary as you'll likely be able to find.

Comment: Plans for legendary drops on any difficulty, the legendary they create will be level appropriate for where they drop.